# Make responsive toolbar Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have to make quasi-responsive toolbar on website. For now, my html look like this (it's part of bigger file):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block table-full-width">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="toolbar">
              <button class="btn btn-info float-left">loremi</button>
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-simple float-right"><i class="fas fa-info"></i></button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-icon float-right"><i class="fas fa-info"></i></button>
              <button class="btn btn-primary float-right"><i class="fas fa-info"></i></button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger float-left">loremi</button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger float-left">lorem ipsum dolor s</button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger float-left">lorem ipsum dolors</button>
              <input type="text" class='float-right col-md-6 mr-3'>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On full width desktop it look as I want (it's only bootstrap classes, I didn't add my own css code yet). Problems begin when I reduce the browser:

[image]

[image]

I could do it using a pure flexbox, but it must be done with the bootstrap and I'm just starting to learn this.

I want to have buttons on the left side one on top of the other on small devices (right icon buttons the same on the right side). Can I do it using only Bootstrap? How I need to rebuild my html and add css?

Comment: You should be using the grid and block-level buttons for layout. Skip the float classes.

Comment: I have to pack this three section in .col divs? For example: four buttons with text in .col-md-6 div, input in .col-md-4 div and three icon in .col-md-2 div? When I using btn-block on button, they take 100% of parent width. Should I use the block class on the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made you one approach using **col-x** classes. But i'm sure there is a better way to do this, like using a [nabvar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/) for example.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-/rXc/GQVaYpyDdyxK+ecHPVYJSN9bmVFBvjA/9eOB+pb3F2w2N6fc5qB9Ew5yIns" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row border border-gray">
    <div id="left-section" class="col-4">
      <div class="row">
        <button class="col-md-3 btn btn-sm btn-info">loremi</button>
        <button class="col-md-3 btn btn-sm btn-danger">loremi</button>
        <button class="col-md-3 btn btn-sm btn-danger">lorem ipsum</button>
        <button class="col-md-3 btn btn-sm btn-danger">lorem ipsum</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="middle-section" class="col-6">
      <input type="text" class="w-100 m-1">
    </div>
    <div id="right-section" class="col-2">
      <div class="row">
        <button class="col-md-4 btn btn-sm btn-primary">
          <i class="fas fa-info"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="col-md-4 btn btn-sm btn-danger">
            <i class="fas fa-info"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="col-md-4 btn btn-sm btn-primary">
            <i class="fas fa-info"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```